# Is Pakistan's nuclear capability giving it an advantage in its foreign relations and diplomacy?

Tags: nuclear-weapons, pakistan

we all know that nuclear weapons give deterrence. But, this question is about diplomacy and foreign relations.

Is Pakistan's nuclear capability giving it an advantage in its foreign relations and diplomacy?

Comment: well if you can't be intimidated by your neighbor with whom you have a territorial dispute, that would be an advantage, no?

Comment: Without unsurpassable nuclear power, I think it is a potential weapon for suicide rather than an advantage. Yes, you can "threaten" to nuke the others, but people will soon realize the hollowness of such a threat due to the deadly consequence you are to bear as well as the country you have flattened.

Comment: It gives **both** advantages and disadvantages. This varies from audience to audience.

Comment: I would assume the answer today would be no. There are so many other aspects of relations and I don't see why this would have a significant impact. Either they have the bomb themselves, or else they don't feel threatent by it.